# Convert array of objects (sort of groupby)

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, ecmascript-6

I call a service that returns a list of questions. Then, I regroup this question by theme.
i have this conversion :

```js
var questions = [
  {
    id: 1,
    label: 'lorem ispum ?',
    theme: {
      id: 1,
      label: 'dog',
    }
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    label: 'lorem ispum2 ?',
    theme: {
      id: 2,
      label: 'horse',
    }
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    label: 'lorem ispum3 ?',
    theme: {
      id: 1,
      label: 'dog',
    }
  },
];

var groupByTheme = questions.reduce(function(obj,item){
    obj[item.theme.label] = obj[item.theme.label] || [];
    obj[item.theme.label].push(item);
    return obj;
}, {});

/*var result = Object.keys(groupsByTheme).map(function(key){
    return {theme: key, questions: groupsByTheme[key]};
});
*/

var result = Object.entries(groupByTheme).map(([theme, questions]) => ({ theme, questions }));

console.log(result);
```

It works. 
But now, i would like to add a property : the id of theme.

```
{
    "themeId": 1,
    "theme": "dog",
    "questions": [...]
},
{
    "themeId": 2,
    "theme": "horse",
    "questions": [...]
}
```

I don't find the right way without having a missy code.

Any suggestions ? 
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could greate the missing parts by getting the result set in the final stage.

I changed the key from `theme` to `id`, because `id` looks more unique.

```js
var questions = [{ id: 1, label: 'lorem ispum ?', theme: { id: 1, label: 'dog' } }, { id: 2, label: 'lorem ispum2 ?', theme: { id: 2, label: 'horse' } }, { id: 3, label: 'lorem ispum3 ?', theme: { id: 1, label: 'dog' } }],
    groupByTheme = questions.reduce(function (obj, item) {
        obj[item.theme.id] = obj[item.theme.id] || [];
        obj[item.theme.id].push(item);
        return obj;
    }, {}),
    result = Object.entries(groupByTheme).map(([id, questions]) => ({
        id,
        theme: questions[0].theme.label,                              // add this
        questions
    }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: oh yes, i feel like stupid :) Too long focused on the same problem ^^

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4) library for that. Then the code will be pretty clean. I'll first make the `themeMap` object which would be map from `label` to `id` as :

```
const themeMap = {};
_.forEach(questions, question => themeMap[question.theme.label] = question.theme.id);
```

Then we can use the `groupBy` and `map` of lodash and code will be really clean as :

```
const result = _.map(_.groupBy(questions, question => question.theme.label), (group, key) => {
    return {questions: group, theme: key, themeId: themeMap[key]};
});
```

The code will be less messy. 
If you don't want to use lodash then you can achieve groupBy by `reduce` of javascript which you already did.

Comment: yes, but i didn't want include this external library for just one case in my application. But thanks ! It'll can help maybe others developers.

Answer (score 0):

When you group the questions by the theme name, you can create the exact "theme" object that you want `{ "themeId": 1, "theme": "dog", "questions": [] }`, and push the question into the `questions` prop. To convert to array use [Object#values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values).

```js
var questions = [{"id":1,"label":"lorem ispum ?","theme":{"id":1,"label":"dog"}},{"id":2,"label":"lorem ispum2 ?","theme":{"id":2,"label":"horse"}},{"id":3,"label":"lorem ispum3 ?","theme":{"id":1,"label":"dog"}}];

var result = Object.values( // get an array of theme objects
  questions.reduce(function(obj,item){
      obj[item.theme.label] = obj[item.theme.label] || 
        Object.assign({ questions: [] }, item.theme); // create an object that includes theme data, and an empty array for questions

      obj[item.theme.label].questions.push(item); // push into questions

      return obj;
  }, {})
);

console.log(result);
```